# Grunt Uglify Failing on ES6 For...of

Tags: javascript, npm, ecmascript-6, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

I'm using grunt to uglify three JavaScript files:

1. functions.js
2. formdata.min.js
3. page-contact.js

I'm getting this error:

```
Warning: Uglification failed.
Name expected.
Line 38 in src/js/functions.js
 Use --force to continue.
```

Line 38 of `functions.js`:

```
for (var [id, value] of formData.entries()) {
```

Is this failing on the for...of or the formData?

The `Gruntfile.js`:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    watch: {
      uglify: {
        files: [ 'src/js/*' ],
        tasks: 'uglify'
      }
    },
    uglify: {
      my_target: {
        files: {
          'public/js/<%= pkg.name %>.min.js': ['src/js/*.js']
        }
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');

};
```

Comment: Does uglify support ES6 yet?

Comment: I'm not sure... According to [this article](https://swizec.com/blog/fun-surprise-uglifyjs-cant-es6/swizec/7272), no. But that was two years ago. Do I need to add babel?

Answer (score 2):

Solved this by switching to the [harmony branch](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify/tree/harmony) of `grunt-contrib-uglify`. The master branch doesn't support ES6 at this time.

In my packages.json I swapped out the original line for this and ran `npm install`:

```
"grunt-contrib-uglify": "git://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify.git#harmony"
```

Comment: why is it locked